# Alternatives to using "from - to" with dates

Tags: prepositions, dates

Is there a correct and formally accepted shorter alternative to "from ... to ..." when referring to a specific period of time?

e.g. *They have their annual forum meeting in Las Vegas from 10 to 12 October*

I've seen this next version often, but I'm not sure if it's correct usage:

*They have their annual forum meeting in Las Vegas, 10-12 October* (with the comma sometimes omitted)

Comment: What is it about the "from ... to ..." format that is unsuitable for your use?

Comment: In a coding context, "between 10/10/2019 and 12/10/2019", and in your particular context "between 10th and 12th October".

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.